# How to apply gaussian filter to raw audio files Python?

Tags: python, scipy, audio-processing

I am recording raw files in python to later break them into phonemes, but the noise in the surrounding environment is hampering the result. So, there is a need to apply a filter to the recorded raw audio files. How can this be done ??

Comment: Take a look at SciPy's signal module (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html), specifically lfilter command and friends, and also the filter design commands. If you need help with filter design parameters and methods, better to ask on https://dsp.stackexchange.com. If you have a specific programming question on implementing this in Python, ask a new question with the code that you have written, and the specific outcome or bug that you need help with.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. Thanks for the replay.